# Python: Loop with possible AttributeErrors

Tags: python, try-catch, hasattr

I have an array `row`. I want to add a set of attributes of an object `actor` to to the array. However, not all actors have each of the attributes.

I want to run a loop that will add the attribute if it exists, but add `'none'` if it does not.

I can't seem to find a way to do the testing in the loop, using either `try` or `hasattr`. This is as far as I got. Of course, it does not work, because the attributes are referenced outside of the loop:

```
for attribute in [actor.x, actor.y, actor.parent, actor.force, actor.hunger, actor.size]:
    try:
        row.append(attribute)
    except AttributeError:
        row.append('none')
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: why do all actors not have the same attributes? to me it sounds like your life may be easier if all actors inherit the same object,  and if a particular actor doesnt have .force, then assign self.force = None. `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.`

Comment: To extend TehTris' question: what are you trying to achieve? Tossing attributes into a list seems like a good way to lose information and gain I-know-not-what.

Comment: Or, maybe `actor` shouldn't be an object (or namedtuple or namespace or whatever) at all, but rather a dictionary. Or maybe an object with a single `attributes` member that is a dictionary.

Comment: Following up: In Python (unlike, say, JS or Ruby) attribute dot-access and dict key-access are different, for a reason: attributes are harder to access dynamically, and easier to access statically, which encourages you to choose the right type for the right job. Occasionally you have to fight the language on this (e.g., by using `getattr`), but usually if you step back and take another look you'll see that it's your design that's at fault, not Python's assumptions.

Comment: @TehTris, msw, abarnert:

Actor is a parent class, with multiple levels of child inheritance. I could initialize every variable in every child class, but that would mean initializing a whole ton of unused variables. Is that really wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for attribute in ['x', 'y', 'parent', 'force', 'hunger', 'size']:
    row.append(getattr(actor, attribute, 'none'))
```

`getattr` takes an optional 3rd argument setting a default value for if the object doesn't have the attribute.

Some notes here:

Why are some of these actors missing attributes? Should they instead have `'none'` or `None` or some other default value?

Lists of strings are prone to bugs, due to implicit string literal concatenation. This is one of many good reasons to get a linting tool, if you're not using one already.

Are you sure you want `'none'` as a default? It might make more sense to use `None`, or a zero-like value of whatever type the attributes are expected to be. (If they're expected to be strings, `'none'` may make sense.)

Comment: +1 but I would suggest `None` as a sentinel value because `bool('none')` → True where `bool(None)` → False

Comment: @msw: Extended my answer.

Comment: @user2357112, The actors are missing attributes because actor is a parent class of many child classes. There are no actor instances that are not also a child class. They are expected to be strings; this is part of a logging function that outputs a list of actors as a CSV. Thanks for the comments and suggestions, feedback is definitely appreciated.

Comment: @user2357112, Also, I think the first argument to `getattr` should be actor, not row.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson: Yep. Fixed.